# Error 401: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working to create a social authentication feature using Django social auth, for now with google, and Facebook, but I get this Error 401: invalid_clientThe OAuth client was not found.
I have tried creating a new project and credentials. I looked at some tutorials and they seem to work flawlessly, not sure what I might be missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DaImTo anything more i need to add?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  Not an image!